How to display eCharts labels in two unrelated groups on scatter chart
I am creating an interactive scatter chart with eCharts in Angular, that will potentially have a very large data set. I have two groupings of points that will be displayed on the same chart.
I want to separate the labels, line one group of labels up at the top and the other beneath the data points. They have a lot of overlap, so I am using labellayout: { moveOverlap: 'shiftX' }.
However, the 'shiftX' option only looks for x Axis overlap, so if one label is at the top of the chart and another is at the bottom of the chart, it will still separate their x positions. It looks very strange and is not an efficient way to display the data. I can't figure out how to use 'shiftX' separately on each half of the labels - I've tried putting them into separate grids/axes/series, etc.
Any ideas?
Here's my code - I modified one of the eCharts examples to illustrate my dilemma. I can turn on hideOverlap if the points are actually dense, but for this example, if you take off the 'shiftX' on either series, the other looks perfect. And the series without the 'shiftX' is a mess.
When both have 'shiftX', more organized mess, but way more overlap than is necessary for the data set size, because it is trying to minimize overlap horizontally among ALL labels, not just the top row or the bottom row.
const data = [
  [[28604,77,17096869,'Australia',1990],[31163,77.4,27662440,'Canada',1990],[1516,68,1154605773,'China',1990],[13670,74.7,10582082,'Cuba',1990],[28599,75,4986705,'Finland',1990],[29476,77.1,56943299,'France',1990],[31476,75.4,78958237,'Germany',1990],[28666,78.1,254830,'Iceland',1990],[1777,57.7,870601776,'India',1990],[29550,79.1,122249285,'Japan',1990],[2076,67.9,20194354,'North Korea',1990],[12087,72,42972254,'South Korea',1990],[24021,75.4,3397534,'New Zealand',1990],[43296,76.8,4240375,'Norway',1990],[10088,70.8,38195258,'Poland',1990],[19349,69.6,147568552,'Russia',1990],[10670,67.3,53994605,'Turkey',1990],[26424,75.7,57110117,'United Kingdom',1990],[37062,75.4,252847810,'United States',1990]],
  [[44056,81.8,23968973,'Australia',2015],[43294,81.7,35939927,'Canada',2015],[13334,76.9,1376048943,'China',2015],[21291,78.5,11389562,'Cuba',2015],[38923,80.8,5503457,'Finland',2015],[37599,81.9,64395345,'France',2015],[44053,81.1,80688545,'Germany',2015],[42182,82.8,329425,'Iceland',2015],[5903,66.8,1311050527,'India',2015],[36162,83.5,126573481,'Japan',2015],[1390,71.4,25155317,'North Korea',2015],[34644,80.7,50293439,'South Korea',2015],[34186,80.6,4528526,'New Zealand',2015],[64304,81.6,5210967,'Norway',2015],[24787,77.3,38611794,'Poland',2015],[23038,73.13,143456918,'Russia',2015],[19360,76.5,78665830,'Turkey',2015],[38225,81.4,64715810,'United Kingdom',2015],[53354,79.1,321773631,'United States',2015]]
];

option = {
  xAxis: [{
    splitLine: { show: false }
  },
  {
    splitLine: { show: false }
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    splitLine: { show: false },
    scale: true,
  },
  {
    splitLine: { show: false },
    scale: true,
  }],
  grid: {
    left: 40,
    right: 130
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: '1990',
      data: data[0],
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      type: 'scatter',
      symbolSize: function (data) {
        return Math.sqrt(data[2]) / 5e2;
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'self'
      },
      labelLayout: function () {
        return {
          y: myChart.getHeight() - 750,
          moveOverlap: 'shiftX'
        };
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          color: '#bbb'
        }
      },
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (param: any) {
          return param.data[3];
        },
        position: 'right',
        minMargin: 2
      }
    },
    {
      name: '1990',
      data: data[1],
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      type: 'scatter',
      symbolSize: function (data) {
        return Math.sqrt(data[2]) / 5e2;
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'self'
      },
      labelLayout: function () {
        return {
          y: myChart.getHeight() - 30,
          moveOverlap: 'shiftX'
        };
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          color: '#bbb'
        }
      },
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (param: any) {
          return param.data[3];
        },
        position: 'right',
        minMargin: 2
      }
    }
  ]
};


You could try putting two charts on top of each other. Using two separate grids doesnt work unfortunately.

It is true that the LabelManager will get all the labels
of the chart and distribute all of those that  have moveOverlap: 'shiftX' regardless of the series they belong to.
One tricky/hacky way to solve this conundrum is to set moveOverlap: 'shiftX' in different stages for each of the series. More precisely, you may set initially shiftX for the first series and not for the other(s). After the chart finished, collect the actual x positions of the labels of the first series and replace shiftX by explicit x values, while adding moveOverlap: 'shiftX' for the second series and update the chart through .setOption. If there are n series, this can be repeated
n-1 times.
Here's your code with this trick applied:


const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

const data = [
    [[28604,77,17096869,'Australia',1990],[31163,77.4,27662440,'Canada',1990],[1516,68,1154605773,'China',1990],[13670,74.7,10582082,'Cuba',1990],[28599,75,4986705,'Finland',1990],[29476,77.1,56943299,'France',1990],[31476,75.4,78958237,'Germany',1990],[28666,78.1,254830,'Iceland',1990],[1777,57.7,870601776,'India',1990],[29550,79.1,122249285,'Japan',1990],[2076,67.9,20194354,'North Korea',1990],[12087,72,42972254,'South Korea',1990],[24021,75.4,3397534,'New Zealand',1990],[43296,76.8,4240375,'Norway',1990],[10088,70.8,38195258,'Poland',1990],[19349,69.6,147568552,'Russia',1990],[10670,67.3,53994605,'Turkey',1990],[26424,75.7,57110117,'United Kingdom',1990],[37062,75.4,252847810,'United States',1990]],
    [[44056,81.8,23968973,'Australia',2015],[43294,81.7,35939927,'Canada',2015],[13334,76.9,1376048943,'China',2015],[21291,78.5,11389562,'Cuba',2015],[38923,80.8,5503457,'Finland',2015],[37599,81.9,64395345,'France',2015],[44053,81.1,80688545,'Germany',2015],[42182,82.8,329425,'Iceland',2015],[5903,66.8,1311050527,'India',2015],[36162,83.5,126573481,'Japan',2015],[1390,71.4,25155317,'North Korea',2015],[34644,80.7,50293439,'South Korea',2015],[34186,80.6,4528526,'New Zealand',2015],[64304,81.6,5210967,'Norway',2015],[24787,77.3,38611794,'Poland',2015],[23038,73.13,143456918,'Russia',2015],[19360,76.5,78665830,'Turkey',2015],[38225,81.4,64715810,'United Kingdom',2015],[53354,79.1,321773631,'United States',2015]]
];

let labelsXBySeries = Array(data.length-1).fill(null); // may be attached to the chart instance if global variables are an issue

const option = {
    xAxis: [{
        splitLine: { show: false }
    },
        {
            splitLine: { show: false }
        }],
    yAxis: [{
        splitLine: { show: false },
        scale: true,
    },
        {
            splitLine: { show: false },
            scale: true,
        }],
    grid: {
        left: 40,
        right: 130
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: '1990',
            data: data[0],
            xAxisIndex: 0,
            yAxisIndex: 0,
            type: 'scatter',
            symbolSize: function (data) {
                return Math.sqrt(data[2]) / 5e2;
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'self'
            },
            labelLayout: function (params) {
                const layout = {y: 0}; // use the y value for this series
                if(labelsXBySeries[params.seriesIndex]){ // if x positions were computed
                    layout.x = labelsXBySeries[params.seriesIndex][params.dataIndex];
                }
                else{ // if not, use `shiftX` to set the positions
                    layout.moveOverlap = 'shiftX';
                }
                return layout;
            },
            labelLine: {
                show: true,
                lineStyle: {
                    color: '#bbb'
                }
            },
            label: {
                show: true,
                formatter: function (param) {
                    return param.data[3];
                },
                position: 'top',
                minMargin: 2
            }
        },
        {
            name: '2015',
            data: data[1],
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            yAxisIndex: 1,
            type: 'scatter',
            symbolSize: function (data) {
                return Math.sqrt(data[2]) / 5e2;
            },
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'self'
            },
            labelLayout: {
                y: myChart.getHeight() - 30
            },
            labelLine: {
                show: true,
                lineStyle: {
                    color: '#bbb'
                }
            },
            label: {
                show: true,
                formatter: function (param) {
                    return param.data[3];
                },
                position: 'bottom',
                minMargin: 2
            }
        }
    ]
};

function collectSeriesLabelsX(chart, seriesIndex){
    const labelManager = Object.entries(chart._api)
        .filter(([prop])=>prop.match(/^__ec_/))
        .find(([_, o])=>o.hasOwnProperty('labelManager'))[1].labelManager;
    const labelsX = [];
    labelManager._labelList.forEach(label=>{
        if(label.seriesModel.seriesIndex === seriesIndex){
            labelsX[label.dataIndex] = label.label.x;
        }
    });
    return labelsX;
}

myChart.on('finished', () => {
    const firstNull = labelsXBySeries.findIndex(labels => labels === null);
    if(firstNull < 0){
        labelsXBySeries.forEach((_, i, a) => {a[i] = null;});
        return;
    }
    labelsXBySeries[firstNull] = collectSeriesLabelsX(myChart, firstNull);
    if(firstNull === labelsXBySeries.length - 1){
        // the last series
        option.series[firstNull + 1].labelLayout.moveOverlap = 'shiftX';
    }
    //option.animation = false; // to speed up the process
    myChart.setOption(option);
});

myChart.setOption(option);
<div id='chart' style='height: 250px; min-width: 1000px'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js"></script>




This is perfect, solves my problem. Took me a bit to translate into Angular, if anyone tries to do this in the future, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts has the event list, so I added a (chartFinished)="myFunction($event)" to the HTML and put the collection of the X values in that function. I also have some dataZoom elements on my final product, so I set the dataZoom event to also aim at that function.

Do you happen to know if there is more documentation somewhere about how the label  manager and similar eCharts functionality works? I wasn't able to dig this deep on the https://echarts.apache.org/ website.

@bleujaiz I'm afraid there isn't much documentation on these; they are internals of the library so they are not part of the features that end users are supposed to be using. As for developers, I am not aware of any documentation they might be using. For me, the only resource is to look at the source code.
